# Take a screenshot with Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-cpp

I just learn how to use cucumber.
Can you tell me how to complete this code?

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

```
Then /^I take a screenshot$/ do
    pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Comment: Give more information... Which language you use?

Answer (score 9):

Screenshots in general are taken when something unexpected occurs. You may also want to capture a screenshot to report when a test case fails. In this particular case, you should have screenshot capture logic in an [@After](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/java/After.html) method that will be executed for every scenario. A Java, selenium version,

```
@After("@browser")
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png"); //stick it in the report
    }
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am providing the code which will take the snapshot when scenario is failed, I hope you can modify according to your uses, Comment here if you can't do that. This code is in ruby with Ubuntu system

```ruby
#Create a directory for storing snapshot
dir_path = "/home/vchouhan/vijay_work/snapshot"
unless Dir.exist?(dir_path)
    Dir.mkdir(dir_path,0777)
    puts "=========Directory is created at #{dir_path}"
else
    puts "=========Directory is exist at #{dir_path}"
end

#Run after each scenario
After do |scenario|
  #Check, scenario is failed?
  if(scenario.failed?)
         time = Time.now.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S_')
         name_of_scenario = time + scenario.name.gsub(/\s+/, "_").gsub("/","_")
         puts "Name of snapshot is #{name_of_scenario}"
         file_path = File.expand_path(dir_path)+'/'+name_of_scenario +'.png'
         page.driver.browser.save_screenshot file_path
         puts "Snapshot is taken"
    puts "#===========================================================#"
    puts "Scenario:: #{scenario.name}"
    puts "#===========================================================#"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use canned steps (pre-defined) to take screenshot.

   ```
   Then take picture
   ```

There is not need for any step definition. Cucumber also comes with many other pre-defined steps. See other [canned steps](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/02-Predefined-steps)

2. If  you still need to write step definition.

   ```
   Then /^I take a screenshot$/ do
     page.save_screenshot('image_name.png')
   end
   ```

Comment: I think you linked canned steps for Calabash, not Cucumber

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea as it seems to introduce a synthetic step just for screenshots which is in no way related to the business scenario being tested. 

Better to use a Cucumber hook so screenshots can be decided to be taken after each step is executed.

Comment: @BigKahuna It depends on whether you are using this step purely for debugging purposes only - and whether you also make this a function to use when you are going through step definitions too.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can implement this step like so,

```
@Then("^I take a screenshot$")
public void i_take_a_screenshot()
{
  // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea as it seems to introduce a synthetic step just for screenshots which is in no way related to the business scenario being tested. Better to use a Cucumber hook so screenshots can be decided to be taken after each step is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using watir-webdriver for your testing you can call the screenshot method on your browser object and save it. http://watirwebdriver.com/screenshots/

If you are doing windows controls you could use the win32/screenshot gem to achieve this.https://github.com/jarmo/win32screenshot

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of the previous answer. This has error handling, writing out the URL at the failure point. Thought it might be useful.

```
@After("@UI" )
public void embedScreenshotOnFail(Scenario s) {
    if (s.isFailed()) {
        try {
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) getDefaultDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            s.embed(screenshot, "image/png" );
            s.write("URL at failure: " + getDefaultDriver().getCurrentUrl());
        } catch (WebDriverException wde) {
            s.write("Embed Failed " + wde.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            cce.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```